# Отправка изображение на сервер вместе с дополнительными строковыми полями используя retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

```
@Multipart
@FormUrlEncoded //тут выдает ошибку, но без нее нельзя использовать @FieldMap
@POST("user/update")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> mapUser);
```

Если отправлять без `@FieldMap Map<String, String> mapUser` то приходит в лог `Ок`, а на сервере ничего нет.

Answer (score 3):

Так как это Multipart запрос, то вместо `@FieldMap` вам нужен `@PartMap`:

```
@Multipart
@POST("user/update")
Call<ServerResponse> uploadFile(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
        @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> mapUser);
```

Получит `RequestBody` из `String` можно так:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), string);
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap).